# Working with .net dll Object in ColdFusion

Tags: c#, dll, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am attempting to access a .dll from ColdFusion 8,0,1,195765 and I am receiving the following error. As a preface, let me iterate I have very, very little exposure to .NET and Visual Studio

```
Class Calculator.Calculator not found in the specified assembly list.
The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute.
```

[here is my dll in the object browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQpSB.png)

```
using System;
namespace Calculator
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int addition(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int subtraction(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my CFML

```
<cfobject type = ".NET" name = "calc" class = "Calculator.Calculator" 
        assembly="c:\test\Calculator.dll">
```

Obviously, the calculator class exists in the dll.

Comment: What happens if you try to put only `class = "Calculator"` ?

Comment: `Class Calculator not found in the specified assembly list. `

Comment: And obviously, you put the DLL in the path you gave in the assembly, right?

Comment: Can you try to move that dll to the folder where the CF exe or process runs? And is that dll compiled as AnyCPU or as X64? The dll is self-contained? It doesn't depend on anything else? I suspect a fusion issue, you might have to enable logging to find the root cause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check the project properties. Is the project "com visible"?